# Delete button for list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating this shopping list app. The app is working fine but I am facing an issue with delete button. I want to show a button when I check the check box. It is happening in current app but it is populating the delete button for all the items in the list.

I only want to populate it for the checkbox that I select, I mean where I have checkbox selected and strikethrough applied.

Sample code -

```
/*Checkbox Strikethrough Item Text */
    $('input.check').change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.item').toggleClass('strike');
        $('.delete_item').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

You can find full working code at this JS Fiddle -

```
http://jsfiddle.net/varunksaini/Zjxq5/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

```
/*Checkbox Strikethrough Item Text */
$('input.check').change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.item').toggleClass('strike', this.checked);
    $(this).closest('li').find('.delete_item').toggleClass('hidden', !this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zmxfH/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).parents('li').find('.delete_item').removeClass('hidden');
```

looks through parents of clicked checkbox searching for element matching 'li' selector, finds its child with delete_item class and shows it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
$('input.check').change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.item').toggleClass('strike');
        $(this).parent().next().removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents('li').children('.delete_item').removeClass('hidden');
```